# Git submodule most recent common commit

Tags: git

I work on a fairly large project that has a "common" submodule and several client repos, with more branches and tags than you can count...

Is there a standard way to, given a certain commit in the "common" submodule, list the commits in the clients that point to that specific commit?

Comment: If it is between repositories - I do not believe there are built in ways of doing so. You might be better of writing a shell script for the task.